# IronPython running UI on a separate thread and opening a file dialog WinForms

Tags: python, winforms, clr, ironpython

I am having a deadlock when trying to open a file dialog from a separate thread using WinForms:

```
class Form(System.Windows.Forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        button0 = Button()
        button0.Location = System.Drawing.Point(10, 120)
        button0.Click += self.Dialog
        self.Controls.Add(button0)
    def Dialog(self, sender, event):
        dialog = OpenFileDialog()
        dialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
        if dialog.ShowDialog():
            print("YES")      
    def Show(self):
        self.ShowDialog()
    def Run(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.Show)
        t1.start()
```

Comment: What is your question?
Do you want to know why the deadlock occurs? — provide more information: how you start your message pump, what is your main form, how do you use your `Form`.
Do you want to know how to avoid the deadlock? — explain what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: I think he trying to know how can be runned winform showdialog in thread ironpython